# FB graph cover photo has offset_y > 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cover

Following [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/cover-photo/) I would expect the cover photo of a given page to have offset_y between 0 and 100. Here is the response I get:

```
{'cover_id': '1002344733110934',
 'id': '1002344733110934',
 'offset_x': 0,
 'offset_y': 105,
 'source': 'xxxx'}
```

Any idea why I get that? Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: Their implementation of those offset values isn’t as straight-forward as one might expect. I suggest you go look through some other questions on the topic, and see if you find something that works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+cover+offset

Comment: I have no issue to do manipulations with it, the only issue I find is that the values returned by their API is inconsistent with their documentation. And also is not very logic..

Comment: Well then you can go and file a documentation bug. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/